# Handle multiple mouses

Tags: windows, winapi, mouse

We are going to use **single PC** ( thin client ) with Windows XP ( Embedded ) with **Dual Monitor**.

[image: One of korean bank]

- **First Monitor** : used by Bank
  Officer ( mouse and keyboard ) *officer will use browser,also some banking win32 apps*
- **Second monitor (touch screen - elotouch)** : used by visitor sitting opposite to Officer *visitor supposed to touch
  feedback html buttons in browser
  (second window), without interrupting
  operators's mouse moves*.

Both screens has it's own browser window opened (may be child window)
Our goal is to achieve mouse and touchscreen work with two browser windows independently.

Now we can read both mouse and touchscreen using `raw inputs` ( see links below ) and can determine which device generating events. 
Our idea is to intercept `raw_input` events from touchscreen in  `ActiveX` component and send it to JS, and cancel propagating events, so touchscreen events won't disturb primary mouse.

Question : **How to cancel propagating (LEGACY) events from particular HID (mouse) device, оr if there are over ways to make it work**, could some one point or share info about how to achieve this ( MSDN or smth ) since we don't have much experience in writing drivers.

Comment: I Found these links

http://cpnmouse.sourceforge.net/
http://www.dailycomputersolutions.com/blog/index.php/2008/11/01/multiple-mouse-cursors-on-a-windows-desktop/

RAW Input
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543%28VS.85%29.aspx
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmousekeyboa/
http://grouplab.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/software/SDGT/

Comment: Install Linux and an X server. It's trivial to disable mice in xorg.conf!

Comment: We checked MultipointSDK also, but trying to find other ways, it has main disadvantage, it working only within own application, unless if we embedd browser into our application.

Comment: Thx Matti! But there are some client applications running only on Win32

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/f3fc4e11-5a60-4bd9-8ec6-913b335de640                 

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/12927/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645546%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536.aspx

Comment: I asked EloTouch guys to help, but they wrote this _Unfortunately, we do not support that type of setup due to Windows, natively, only supports control of one mouse cursor at a time. There is an interesting article on the Microsoft site that may be useful: http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/developer.aspx we have not tested this or know if will work with a touchscreen but it might be something to look into_

Comment: EloTouch answered second time, about how to calibrate touchscreen only on second monitor. _Yes, you use the same setup only one will not be a touchscreen. When doing the alignment if the targets appear on the non-touch monitor, hit the ESC key on your keyboard and it will move to the touchmonitor._

Comment: I found Driver http://www.touchkit.com/, an API function `EnableTouch(hFile,false);` you could turn off MouseEmulationMode and register callback function `RegisterTPNotifyMessage` which registers a notification message for touch event so that the window can receive the message whenever touch

Answer (score 0):

> How to cancel propagating (LEGACY)
>   events from particular HID (mouse)
>   device?

Mouse messages are posted to the input thread's message queue.  Mouse messages are in the range `WM_MOUSEFIRST` to `WM_MOUSELAST`. The simplest approach is to modify your message pump so that it swallows messages in this range.

Arrange that your message pump looks like this:

```
while(GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 ))
{ 
    if ((msg.message<WM_MOUSEFIRST) || (msg.message>WM_MOUSELAST))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with something similar a few years ago so forgive me for being a bit vague but I think I had some success locking the cursor to the primary screen with ClipCursor which is in the user32 API...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383(v=vs.85).aspx

... then when a mouse event comes in from the touch device because it is outside the clip region it was ignored but the WM_INPUT events are still fired so you can capture them and post your own mouse click events directly to the browser which isn't technically moving the cursor so it isn't affected by the clipping.

It has been a while since I did any of this so please forgive me if this doesn't work. I will try to dig out my old prototypes tomorrow and see if I find any gems.

Comment: Good point, thnx! But how to achieve touch device work in separate area (outside clip region), it will also be inside clip region in first monitor. or i misunderstood smthg ?

Comment: I can assume what touchdrivers will be calibrated to second monitor, so events from touch will be outside clip region, am i right ?

Comment: Ok, I remembered exactly what I did now. Instead of using ClipCursor to clip to the first screen, you use ClipCursor every time you get a mouse move message from the primary mouse and you set the clip region to a single pixel at the cursor position. That way the second mouse can have no effect on the actual position of the cursor.

Comment: The touch driver should act like a mouse so you should still get mouse events from it. However because you will be restricting the cursor position, normal mouse clicks wont work from the touch driver. You will need to listen to the events yourself and then post mouse messages to the window that should be receiving them. In your case it should be a full screen browser window so it should be relatively easy.